# Make applications similar to Talking Tom Cat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gamekit

I want to make an applications similar to Talking Tom Cat, Touch Pets Cats/, Virtual Monkey and the Tap Zoo.

I have knowledge of Iphone basic animation.

I want to know that can i make these apps without OpenGL ,cocos and other gaming environment...
Can i make it by using only basic frameworks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 approaches

- One - make them as 3d Models with animations. The best suited too for this is Unity3d (it brings down development time to a great extent) But the basic version for iPhone to publish costs 400$. I think its worth it.
- Two - Make all of them as frame animations. Use either Cocos2d or UIImageView's frames to animate it. You need to dealloc and alloc on the fly when you have too many frames due to which you might hit memory warning. You might think loading on the fly would be costly/intensive but its not as much as you would expect, as iDevices have flash memory on them and we have tried this.

I personally would say use 2nd method if you need just a clone. But with 3d models with animations in them, you get more freedom to add creativity like a 3d camera to look around. So you can poke in the butt and have a different animation for it etc. Also you could have overlay texture and do things like adding tattoos to the 3d model.

Answer (score 14):

Well if its related to talking tom then there is no OpenGLES Use... they are simply using images and animate them. using something like this -

```
    aniImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage* opa1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o1.png"];
UIImage* opa2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o2.png"];
UIImage* opa3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o3.png"];
UIImage* opa4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o4.png"];
UIImage* opa5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o5.png"];
UIImage* opa6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o6.png"];
UIImage* opa7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o7.png"];
UIImage* opa8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o8.png"];
UIImage* opa9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o9.png"];
UIImage* opa10 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o10.png"];
UIImage* opa11 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o11.png"];
UIImage* opa12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o12.png"];
UIImage* opa13 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o13.png"];
UIImage* opa14 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o14.png"];
UIImage* opa15 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o15.png"];
UIImage* opa16 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o16.png"];
UIImage* opa17 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o17.png"];
UIImage* opa18 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o18.png"];
NSArray *imgsArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:opa1, opa2, opa3, opa4, 
                          opa5, opa6, opa7, opa8, opa9, opa10, opa11, opa12, opa13, opa14, opa15, opa16, opa17, opa18, nil];
[aniImage setAnimationImages:imagesOpcaity];
[aniImage setAnimationRepeatCount:1.0];
[aniImage setAnimationDuration:0.2];
```

If you wants to see all the images they are using follow these setps -

1) buy the free version on your iPhone/iPad
2) transfer your purchases on your mac or windows.
3) then drag the ipa file from Library -> Apps to your desktop (just drag the app icon from iTunes to desktop)
4) rename the .ipa file to .zip file
5) extract this zip file.
6) you will get a folder named "Payload" in it.
7) open the .app file (it will open on windows automatically because it is a folder on windows, on mac right click on it and select show package content.
8) in the .app folder you will find a folder which contains all the images used by above function.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can make Tap Zoo and other by using images or sprite sheets may be on UIButton or enable user interaction for images. but you have to use alot of coding to implement some like that big, it wouldn't be difficult to accomplish it just many lines of code(seriously many more than 100K). So take my advise and learn cocoa2d or quartzcore2d or opengl that way you will not only learn something new but also be able to make nice games. for opengl start up follow this link

http://appstapnet.blogspot.in/2009/04/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-1-basic.html?m=1

Comment: The 100K estimate is way off, such an application has to fit under 10K (not counting third-party libraries).