# images missing when uploaded to app store

Tags: ios, image, app-store

I have an iOS app with a bunch of images in it.  I used images inside of table view cells and as tab bar images.  When testing for development and distribution everything worked just fine, and Apple approved it and put in on the app store.  Problem is - I checked out my app from the app store and all of the images are gone!  Both image sets are completely absent.  Now, this only happens in the version of the app actually on the app store - the app in Xcode looks fine.  Anyone have any idea what might be causing it?

Much appreciated!

p.s. if it helps to see the app yourself, let me know and I'll post a link.

Comment: have you tested your app on an actual device before submitting it to the store?

Comment: Yes, I have and everything displayed as expected.  Just when submitting and downloading from the store did it disappear.

Comment: @leksah255 were you able to resolve this since i too have encountered this issue today.

Answer (score 0):

Check your targets. In case if you use different target for building for appstore and for adhoc build you may included some of resources only into testing target.

Answer (score 0):

Download your application from appstore, explore it using steps define[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6177242/656600), see if your images are in there, if not then re-upload binary with properly linked images, else, consider answer from @Nikita.